# my homedisk erased, is this malware or a systemfault?

Tags: 20.04, gparted, rsync, malware

After trying to save a spreadsheet, LibreOffice was hanging and could not be used anymore. I recently installed 20.045 so I decided to reinstall it. I first made an rsync of my homedirectory which is on a separate dasd. While rsync was running I noticed messages like `filexxx  ....vanished.....`. I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the rsync. I then discoverd that my entire home-dasd was empty. I then booted 20.10 on the same system, gparted says the home-dasd has 405Mb on it. After mounting it under 20.10 it was empty. Could this be an Ubuntu-error or is it malware?

The command I used was in my homedir so it is gone, I have been using rsync for many years now and the command I used in a script is like:

```
sudo rsync -rtv --delete --exclude=".*" /home/newbie/ /mnt/sda6/rsyncHome2004
```

I have started 20.10 several times after the crash and when I start Gparted it still says that sda6 has 405 Mb on it. If it was a human-error then Gparted should be consistent I think.

---

The command I used was in my homedir so it is gone, I have been using rsync for many years now and the command I used in a script is like
sudo rsync -rtv  --delete --exclude=".*"    /home/newbie/         /mnt/sda6/rsyncHome2004

I have started  20.10 several times after the crash and when I start Gparted it still says that sda6 has 405 Mb on it. If it was a human-error then Gparted should be consistent I think

I have changed the tags of this issue because I think gparted reporting 400 Mb on a disk that is empty when mounted cannot be the result of a user error

I just checked my history to review what happened, here it is:

sudo ./rsyncbatchZ490M7.sh > ./rsyncbatchZ490M505.txt
mount | grep sd
exit
history
mount | grep sd
exit

during the /rsync... shell I noticed a lot of unexpected output like
....vanished...  I then used ctrl-c to stop it. My entire history before the /rsync..  has disappeared. The actual text of the /rsync. shell has diappeared, my entire harddisk is almost empty. The only file in my home-dir is the history-file I showed above. The history-command gives the same output. I can boot my 20.045 partition without problems. The only file visible in Krusader is this history-file. After booting my 20.10 partition and running Gparted it now says that sda7 has now 698.73 Mb in use. I am sure yesterday it said 400 Mb

Comment: Most likely human error. More details about exactly what you did are needed to diagnose.

Comment: "I first made an rsync of my homedirectory" please provide the command. And no Ubuntu does not do that unless instructed to do so ;) and malware generally does not delete content....  malware encrypts your data so you could be persuaded to pay for unlocking it. Far more profitable ;)

Comment: In 14 years of Ubuntu (and Debian before that) on many devices and in many places, all lost data has been due to my own human-error. None has been due to "Ubuntu-error" nor malware.

Comment: I think that first you could try to go back to what you had installed before having the problem with the Microsoft sheet and if you still do not recover your homedisk, you should check if it is malware or a systemfault

Comment: I meant a Libreoffice spreadsheet, I don't use microsoft anymore

Comment: Welcome (back) to Ask Ubuntu!  It looks like it may have been a while since you've been active here.  Since you posted 3 "answers" below that should have been [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1446792/edit) to your question, I'd encourage you to perhaps take the [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) again and to read through some of the [Help](https://askubuntu.com/help) to refamiliarize yourself with how the site works.

Comment: check the output of the `history` command to see exactly what you did